# Does `new` allocate enough memory for any instance?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, new-operator

If I create a `Foo` with

```
Foo* foo = new Foo();
```

then reassign that `foo`

```
Foo mkfoo();

*foo = mkfoo();
```

Can I be sure that I've allocated enough memory for this new instance created by `mkfoo`? Even if `Foo` has dynamically-sized contents e.g. a `std::vector` which has different contents when created with `mkfoo()` than when created with `new Foo()`? If not, what's the best way to allocate the memory?

Comment: Every object of type `Foo` has exactly the same size. This is true for all types. Anything that needs dynamic amounts of memory need to use dynamic memory allocation, which is stored outside of the object itself.

Comment: Every object of type `Foo` has the same size. Every object of type `std::vector<whatever>` has the same size. Adding and removing elements from a vector doesn't  change its size; it changes the dynamic memory that it manages.

Comment: However, that doesn't necessarily mean that you can know in advance that you'll have enough memory for the assignment. The `std::vector` copy constructor might throw if it can't allocate enough memory. If you want to provide your own guarantees for how memory is used you'd have to look at using a custom allocator for the vector.

Comment: Just be aware that the initial heap memory that foo points to is still there when you reassign foo. Also, pointers to vectors is typically a code smell.

Comment: @doug indeed. I'm very restricted in what I can do because I'm working in an FFI world where I can only return pointers

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  Part of the definition of a "complete type" is that its size is known.

For types that contain dynamically-sized members like `std::vector`, the dynamic storage of those members is also allocated on the heap, so the size of that storage is not part of the calculation when considering the `sizeof` the object.

Answer (score 3):

The line

```
*foo = mkfoo();
```

does not create a new `Foo` object in the storage returned from `new`. It simply calls the assignment operator overload on the already present `Foo` object.

Even if you use e.g. a placement-new to actually create a new `Foo` object in the storage returned by the original `new` expression, that is fine, since objects of the same type always have the same object size (`sizeof`) determining the storage size they take up.

If you have a container such as `std::vector<int>`, its own object size (`sizeof`) is also always the same. However it will contain e.g. a pointer to other memory where the elements of the vector are stored (how exactly that is done is an implementation-detail). If you call `.size()` on a `std::vector` you don't get the size of the `std::vector` object, but the number of elements stored by the vector, which are however not stored in the `std::vector` object's memory itself and so don't count towards its object size.